# I have an informatica code.I want to have an equivalent of the same in oracle query

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica-powercenter

```
IIF(Col1=1, DAT1, IIF(Col2=1, DAT2, IIF(col3=1, DAT3, IIF(Col4=1, DAT4))))
```

The above is the informatica piece of code

How do i convert this in oracle

```
case when col1=1 then data1
 else
 case when col2=1 then data2)
```

I have tried something like this.But i am not sure .Please suggest me on how to convert

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple, nested `CASE` statements, one is enough:

```
CASE
  WHEN Col1=1 THEN DAT1
  WHEN Col2=1 THEN DAT2
  WHEN Col3=1 THEN DAT3
  WHEN Col4=1 THEN DAT4
END
```

Comment: Maybe does not apply, but i case any of condition is satisfied, the Oracle solution is always null, and the informatica condition is:
  0 if col4 is a Numeric datatype.  
  Empty col4 if value1 is a String datatype.
  NULL if col4 is a Date/Time datatype.